# Copy-Item Folder Zipped or Unzipped?

Tags: powershell, file-transfer, corruption

Hi im working on replacing 2 folders on 400 ish remote win 7 pcs.

C:\Test
C:\Final

they have started to get way bigger than needed as people dont cleanup after themselves.

they should be ~350 mb  but most are atleast 1.5 gb

So it takes forever when replacing the folders for a user.

So i wanted to just Copy-item over to the remote pcs and let it replace everything from the backups i have.

But my concern is file corruption, So i know you can move zipped folders then unzip them but is that going to slow everything down to a point were its going to just be easier to copy-item then fix the ones that need it?

i plan to just: For Each IP, Delete folders,Copy Folders -Recurse

Am i overthinking this?

Comment: "[...] but is that going to slow everything down [...]?" - the easiest way to find out is to _test it_! Write a script that copies the zip + unzips on the remote, and write another script that just copies the directory and it's contents as-is. Record how long each takes (you can use `Measure-Command` for this) when you run it for just 1 or 2 remote machines.

Comment: `robocopy` when it works may also save time for your users who did "cleanup after themselves"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i know you can move zipped folders then unzip them but is that going to slow everything down

No, it's going to speed everything up. Copying lots of small files will be hurt most by network round-trip latency, checking each file, getting each file permissions, opening each file, writing to it, closing each file, all that will take time.

Copy one zip file, make much more efficient use of the network sending a blob of data with no interruptions. [Make sure to get the remote computer to unzip it locally].

Comment: Thanks guys, ill look into unzipping locally and using robocopy.